# How can I add a caret to text passed to @Html.ActionLink in MVC5

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, caret

I want to display

```
Username v
```

as the text displayed for the link.

I wanted to use `<class = "caret">` but I can't pass it successfully and the HTML code is being printed next to `Username`.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases the Html.ActionLink will do the trick, if you want more control over the href tag you can use @Url.Action.

Examples:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.Username, "Username", "Account", new { @class = "caret" })
```

HTML Result: `<a class="caret" href="/Account/Username">SomeUsername</a>`

```
<a class="caret" href="@Url.Action("Username", "Account")">@Model.Username</a>
```

HTML Result: `<a class="caret" href="/Account/Username">SomeUsername</a>`